# what harm can a malicious ca do?

Tags: tls, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority

If ca's act in the interests of an eavesdropper, what is the worst they cold do?

I guess they can decrypt traffic not using perfect forward secrecy and impersonate the server. Is this the case?

Comment: They can do a man-in-the-middle attack against connections that _are_ using perfect forward secrecy as well. Perfect forward secrecy protects you against a later compromise of the legitimate key, but not against a rogue CA signing an illegitimate key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are talking about a SSL context: rogue CA is trusted by some client to validate the certificate issued to a SSL server.

The rogue CA can create a fake certificate and private key, to be used to impersonate the server. The client will believe that it talks to the genuine server, but in fact it talks to the impersonator. If the impersonator, simultaneously, connects to the true sever as if he was the client, this becomes a [Man-in-the-Middle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). Client and server notice nothing, but the attacker sees everything, and can alter data at will.

Data decryption and forward secrecy are relatively unrelated to that point. In a PKI, the CA does not normally see the servers' private keys. When a server owner wishes to obtain an "SSL certificate" for his server, he generates a new key pair *locally* and sends only the public key to the CA. Since the CA never sees the private key, it cannot use it to decrypt recorded connections, regardless of whether the cipher suite enables [forward secrecy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy) (i.e. a "DHE" cipher suite) or not. The role of the CA is to guarantee the ownership of public keys; if the client really uses the true server's public key, then the cryptography protects the connection, rogue CA or not rogue CA.

However, there are existing CA who are on the habit of generating servers' private keys themselves. They send to their customers the certificate *and* the private key together (usually as a PKCS#12 archive -- aka "pfx file"). They do that because it is simpler: many server administrators, with limited competence at what they do, have trouble handling private keys and certificates when the key pair was generated within their Web browser, on their desktop machine (not on their server). When the CA is rogue *and* generates the private key for the server, then it can keep a copy of the private key and use it to try to decrypt the data. In that case, forward secrecy will be a problem for that eavesdropping rogue CA: use of a DHE cipher suite will force the rogue CA to go to the trouble of running a fake server.

Since MitM attacks are still quite feasible, a rogue CA is a huge problem, and use of forward secrecy is *not* an adequate mitigation.

Comment: How easy is mitm after the client had already interacted with the server? Must a domain registrar be complicit in this, can having different registrar and ca help? Are Ca's required to allow us to generate keys ourselves?

Comment: Whether the client has already interacted with the server or not is irrelevant: SSL clients have no memory (they don't record server keys like SSH clients do). To do a MitM on the cheap, you set up a fake WiFi access point in a fast food restaurant, and wait for customers to connect to it. For a less cheap but more generic method, DNS poisoning is used.

Comment: CA are bound by their own contractual obligations, which can be void for a "lone CA"; but, usually, a CA _inserted by default in Firefox or Internet Explorer_ has made a deal with Mozilla/Microsoft, one term of which being strict compliance to a published Certification Practice Statement, which may include an obligation to let customers generate their own key pairs. However, the CPS does not need contain such a clause.